# Sort database list alphabetically [sql]

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm having trouble sorting my database alphabetically. I assume I need to sort the database here:

```
public static Cursor getAllRecords() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_ITEM},
            null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

I've tried replacing the last `null` with " DESC" which didn't work.
Am I doing this in the wrong spot?

Comment: Do you want to sort it based on your `KEY_ROWID` ? @Logik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like `KEY_ITEM + " DESC"` for the `orderBy` parameter:

```
public static Cursor getAllRecords() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_ITEM},
            null, null, null, null, KEY_ITEM + " DESC");  // note the missing last null for 'limit'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_ITEM}, null, null, null, null, KEY_ITEM+ " ASC");
```

or

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_ITEM}, null, null, null, null, KEY_ITEM+ " DESC");
```